# 2 plots inside subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using suplot2grid to chart 6 subplots and each one of these subplots has 2 time series inside. Each of these subplots should show values in different Y (vertical) axis.
My current output, wich is close to my objective, but still wrong, is like this:
[image]

Right now What I do is the following:

```
fig2    = plt.figure(figsize=(14,11))

# defining the axes

ax1_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)  # drift
ax1_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(4,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a) # zscore drift
ax1_b     = ax1_a.twinx()

ax2_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(4,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a)
ax2_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(8,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a)
ax2_b     = ax2_a.twinx()

ax3_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(8,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a)
ax3_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(11,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a)
ax3_b     = ax3_a.twinx()

ax4_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(0,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1)
ax4_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(4,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax4_a)
ax4_b     = ax4_a.twinx()

ax5_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(4,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax4_a)
ax5_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(8,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax4_a)
ax5_b     = ax5_a.twinx()

ax6_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(8,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax4_a)
ax6_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(11,1), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax4_a)
ax6_b     = ax6_a.twinx()
```

# defining the plotting functions

```
def plot_drift(axx,label):
    axx.plot(df.index[-lenght:], df[label][-lenght:], linestyle='-', lw=2, 
           label=label,color='b',alpha=1.00)

def plot_zscore(axx,label):
    axx.plot(df.index[-lenght:], df[label][-lenght:], linestyle='-', lw=2, 
           label=label,color='g',alpha=1.00)

def vertical_labels_drift(axx):
    axx.set_ylabel('Vols')
def vertical_labels_Zscore(axx):
    axx.set_ylabel('Zscore')

def stdev(axx):
    axx.axhline(2,linewidth=2,color='yellow')   # standard deviations        
    axx.axhline(-2,linewidth=2,color='yellow')  # standard deviations     
    axx.axhline(3,linewidth=2,color='red')           
    axx.axhline(-3,linewidth=2,color='red')


# plotting the drift
for i,j in zip([ax1_a,ax2_a,ax3_a,ax4_a,ax5_a,ax6_a],cols_drift):
    plot_drift(i,j)
    vertical_labels_drift(i)

# plotting the zscore
for i,j in zip([ax1_b,ax2_b,ax3_b,ax4_b,ax5_b,ax6_b], cols_drift_Z):
    plot_zscore(i,j)
    stdev(i)
    vertical_labels_Zscore(i)
```

So my question is, what is the right way of defining the new plot to go inside the subplots?
Because if you put the same location for `ax1_a` and `ax1_b`, `ax1_a` gets overwritten by `ax1_b` and only `ax1_b` gets charted. In other words, if you do this:

```
ax1_a     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)  # drift
ax1_b     = plt.subplot2grid((12,2),(0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1, sharex=ax1_a) # zscore drift
ax1_b     = ax1_a.twinx()
```

`ax1_a` won't show.

Also I don't understand why my charts are showing even with the wrong location inputed in the first code shown. It looks like even if you put a different location to `ax1_b`, `ax2_b`, etc when doing `.twinx()` it kind of resets that chart to the chart that is reffering when doing `.twinx()`.

Comment: So how does the output you're getting differ from what you want?

Comment: @ tjollans It generates a 4th line of empty subplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have misunderstood the role of `axes.twinx()`, you must instantiate an *axes* first, to be used for the first set of curves(ticks on the left) and later use `.twinx()` to have a cloned *axes* on which draw the second set of curves.

A simpler example, that you can adapt to your issues

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,1,101)
nr, nc = 3, 2
fig, axes_array = plt.subplots(nrows=nr, ncols=nc)

for row_of_axes in axes_array:
    for ax in row_of_axes:
        ax.plot(t,np.sin(np.pi*t), color='black')
        ax.twinx().plot(t,2*np.sin(np.pi*t)/(1.1-t), color='red')

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

p.s. closer to your coding style

```
...
for r, row_of_axes in enumerate(axes_array):
    for c, ax_a in enumerate(row_of_axes):
        ax_b = ax_a.twinx()
        ax_a.plot(t,np.sin(np.pi*t), color='black', label='a %d %d'%(r,c))
        ax_b.plot(t,2*np.sin(np.pi*t)/(1.1-t), color='red', label='b %d %d'%(r,c))
        ax_a.legend(loc=1)
        ax_b.legend(loc=3)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

**Addressing OP's comment/request**

In place of a `ndarray` you can simply use a list of lists,

```
nr, nc = 3, 2
axes_array = [[plt.subplot2grid((nr, nc), (r,c)) for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]
```

Note that this differ from my previous code because it doesn't give you a `fig`ure — to apply the tight layout you can proceed like this (untested, caveat emptor)

```
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there a way to iterate like that when defining it as plt.subplot2grid()? it throws "AxesSubplot" object is not iterable.

Comment: I've put the code you need at the end of my answer, ciao